# PDO while loop returning only one row

Tags: php, pdo

I've tried several different versions for PDO while loops and none of them are returning more than one row. The problems is the call to the dreamyPrizes table in the loop. If I take that out it works fine, with it, it only returns one row.

I tried:

```
  $st = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `dreamyAuctions` WHERE `showOnHomePage` =:yes AND `active`=:yes AND `completed`=:no ORDER BY `StartDate`"); // need to filter for next auction
$st->bindParam(':yes', $yes); // filter
$st->bindParam(':no', $no); // filter
$st->bindParam(':gameId', $gameId); // filter
$yes=1;
$no=0;
$st->execute();
$r = $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

<? 
while($r = $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){?>
<?
$auctionId= $r['id'];

$startDate = date("m-d-Y h:i A", strtotime($startDate));

if (strlen($title) > 100)
$title = substr($title, 0, 90) . '...</a>';

$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, FALSE);
$st = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `dreamyPrizes` WHERE `id`=:prizeId"); // need to    filter for next auction
$st->bindParam(':prizeId', $prizeId); // filter
$st->execute();
$r = $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$prizeImage= $r['image1'];
$retailPrice= $r['retailPrice'];
 ?> 

 <div>div to loop</div> <? }?>
```

I also tried

```
do {

$auctionId= $r['id'];

$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, FALSE);
$st = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `dreamyPrizes` WHERE `id`=:prizeId"); // need to filter for next auction
$st->bindParam(':prizeId', $prizeId); // filter
$st->execute();
$rs = $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$prizeImage= $rs['image1'];
$retailPrice= $rs['retailPrice'];

?>
<div>div to loop</div>
<?php } while ($r = $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)); ?>
```

Comment: 1. get rid of useless parameters in the first query. Use JOIN to make it all in **one** query. 3. **ALWAYS** have `error_reporting(E_ALL)` in your scripts

Answer (score -1):

had to change the "st" in the second table to "sts" for it to work

```
$sts = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `dreamyPrizes` WHERE `id`=:prizeId"); // need to filter    for next auction
$sts->bindParam(':prizeId', $prizeId); // filter
$sts->execute();
$rs = $sts->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$prizeImage= $rs['image1'];
$retailPrice= $rs['retailPrice'];`enter code here`
```

Comment: still $prizeId coming out of nowhere

Comment: WOW my rep took a beating with this post. You guys know how long I worked to get this to work?

Answer (score -1):

```
$sql = "SELECT p.* FROM `dreamyAuctions` a JOIN `dreamyPrizes` p 
        ON p.id = a.id
        WHERE `showOnHomePage` = 1 AND `active`= 0 AND `completed`= 0 
        ORDER BY `StartDate`";
$stm = $db->query($sql);
$data = $stm->fetchAll();
```

That's all you need to get your data.
Now you can proceed to output from separated template

```
<? foreach ($data as $row): ?>
<div>div to loop <?=$row['image1']?> <?=$row['retailPrice']?></div>
<? endforeach ?>
```